# Pearson correlation between discrete variable that's mostly 0 and a standard normal variable

Tags: correlation, bias, pearson-r

Suppose I want to estimate the correlation between $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y$, where $Y \in \{-1,0,1\}$ and is equal to zero for 99 per cent of the sample. Sample size is 10 million.

What are the properties of the Pearson correlation in this instance (bias, usefulness, etc)? Would an alternative correlation estimator be better (e.g. a rank correlation)?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues here:

First, the Pearson correlation would be assuming that both variables are continuous. This is not the case here.

Second, when 99% of one variable takes on only 1 value, correlation measures will be limited.

e.g

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- cut(x, breaks = c(-100,-3,3,100), labels = FALSE)
boxplot(x~y)
cor(x,y, method = "spearman")
```

The boxplot shows the perfect relationship, but the correlation is 0.09 (and Spearman's correlation is 0.17). This doesn't seem useful.

What is it you are trying to do, in non-statistical terms?

Comment: Cut down on the number of features I have by identifying those that aren't important, before using something like Lasso (dimensions are too big for numerical algorithms at this stage). I know of much more sophisticated methods that I'm applying but wanted to check the legitimacy of this.

Comment: I don't think it's quite true that Pearson correlation is assuming continuous variables. For example, the Pearson correlation is perfectly well defined for binary variables so long as there is variation in both variables. An even better example is that Spearman correlation is just Pearson correlation on ranks, and ranks are not continuous. It's true that in general Pearson correlation may not be useful for discrete variables, but that's not quite the same point.

Comment: The Pearson correlation on even binary-binary association turns out to be a common measure of association, and in the case of binary-continuous correlation also corresponds to a [well-known measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient). I think it could be reasonable to use it in the current situation.

Comment: OK, Nick and Glen are correct re binary measures. But this isn't a binary one. And the lack of variation seems to be problematic.